# Is there a place i can send my English writing so they can correct it for me?

Tags: discussion, online-resources

I want to create content for my website but I am not a native English speaker, so I will have a lot of errors for sure. I am wondering if there's a place I can send my writings to be checked and corrected.

Can I ask on EL&U? Is there a place specifically for this?